# No optional width parameter for graphics.strokeColor?

Tags: dart, stagexl

The code is not recognize setting the width command:

```
hi.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Red, width: 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [stageXL api](http://www.stagexl.org/docs/api/index.html#stagexl/stagexl.Graphics@id_strokeColor) the `width` attribute is an optional positional attribute. So you don't have to use the `width:` prefix in the method call :

```dart
hi.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Red, 5);
```

See [functions optional parameters](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#functions-optional-parameters) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

From stageXL [api](http://www.stagexl.org/docs/api/index.html#stagexl/stagexl.Graphics@id_strokeColor) your code should be

`hi.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Red, width = 5);`

`=` not `:`

Comment: Indeed. @ferixhu you cannot mix positional and named parameters in Dart.

Comment: That sets the width of the entire sprite to 5. However, hi.width = 5 works just fine.

Comment: The optional `width` parameter is an optional positional argument. You don't use a name for this. You would call it like `strokeColor(Color.Red, 5)` Optional named parameters are enclosed in curly braces and used like in the question.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer. Maybe I should wake up before answering :-)

Comment: @grohjy No prob, I watch you :-P